# Managing ruby versions using RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm running latest Snow Leopard and ran into a problem with ruby versions.

Version 1.8.7 was installed on Mac from the beginning. I installed 1.9.2 using RVM following all instructions. Now when I try to switch to 1.9.2 running `rvm use 1.9.2` it says "using 1.9.2" but when I run `ruby -v` I still get 1.8.7

Seems like preinstalled version of ruby is not under RVM management.

Any ideas on how to get this fixed?

Comment: I think I had a similar problem once! What about uninstalling the 1.8.7 and reinstalling it using RVM?

Comment: Sounds like the preinstalled version appears earlier in your `PATH` than the rvm version.  Is the line that sources rvm the last thing in your bash_profile or bashrc?

Comment: @matt, my bash_profile looks like this: export PATH=~/.rvm/bin/:$PATH
export PATH=/opt/local/bin/:$PATH

Comment: Have a look at the Post Install section here: http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/ Basically you need to remove the `export PATH=~/.rvm/bin/:$PATH` line and add `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` to the end of bash_profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Seems like preinstalled version of ruby is not under RVM management

That is correct. It was preinstalled by Apple, and RVM will not manage it. To revert to using it you can do `rvm system` or `rvm use system`, and RVM will step out of the way. You can switch back using `rvm default` if you defined a default, or `rvm 1.9.2` or `rvm 1.8.7` if you installed one of those versions using RVM.

And, as a caution, Apple installed 1.8.7 to be used by some of their pre-installed apps. Do not mess with that installation or those apps could stop working, which you probably won't notice until farther down the road when you've forgotten you messed around, and can't figure out why they're broken.

As for why you still see 1.8.7 as your default:

- Did you add 
  `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` to your `~/.bashrc` OR `~/.bash_profile`? See the [Post Install](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install) section on RVM's installation page and follow the instructions.
- Did you do `rvm use 1.9.2 --default` to define a default Ruby to use?